# Statsmodels OLS function for multiple regression parameters

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

Lets say I want to find the alpha (a) values for an equation which has something like

```
y=a+ax1+ax2+...+axi
```

Using OLS lets say we start with 10 values for the basic case of i=2

```
#y=a+ax1+ax2

y = np.arange(1, 10)
x = np.array([[ 5, 10], [10,  5], [ 5, 15],
       [15, 20], [20, 25], [25, 30],[30, 35],
       [35,  5], [ 5, 10], [10, 15]])
```

Using statsmodel I would generally the following code to obtain the roots of nx1 x and y array:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = sm.add_constant(x)

# least squares fit
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
fit = model.fit()
alpha=fit.params
```

But this does not work when x is not equivalent to y. The equation is [here](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~tealj2/stat03.pdf) on the first page if you do not know what OLS.

Comment: If you want `y=a+ax1+ax2`, then you have x and y reversed in the code setting up the data. OLS can only handle only one-dimensional y.

Comment: @user333700 Even if you reverse it around it has the same problems of a nx1 array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback tells you what's wrong

```
    raise ValueError("endog and exog matrices are different sizes")
ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes
```

Your x has 10 values, your y has 9 values. A regression only works if both have the same number of observations.

endog is y and exog is x, those are the names used in statsmodels for the independent and the explanatory variables.

If you replace your `y` by

```
y = np.arange(1, 11)
```

then everything works as expected.

Comment: in `alpha=fit.params` I get 4 values back for alpha but I am only solving for 2 where did the other 2 come from?

Comment: you should get 3 values back, one for the constant and two slope parameters. Do you want all coefficients to be equal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic problem with the above, you say you're using 10 items, but you're only using 9 for your vector of y's.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> len(numpy.arange(1, 10))
9
```

This is because slices and ranges in Python go up to but not including the stop integer. If you had done:

```
numpy.arange(10)
```

you would have had a list of 10 items, starting at 0, and ending with 9.

For a regression, you require a predicted variable for every set of predictors. Otherwise, the predictors are useless. You may as well discard the set of predictors that do not have a predicted variable to go with them.